# K means clustering in MATLAB - output image

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, k-means

To perform K means clustering with k = 3 (segments). So I:

1) Converted the RGB img into grayscale

2) Casted the original image into a n X 1, column matrix

3) idx =  kmeans(column_matrix)

4) output = idx, casted back into the same dimensions as the original image.

My questions are :

**A**

When I do imshow(output), I get a plain white image. However when I do imshow(output[0 5]), it shows the output image. I understand that 0 and 5 specify the display range. But why do I have to do this?

**B)**
Now the output image is meant to be split into 3 segments right. How do I threshold it such that I assign  a

0 for the clusters of region 1
1 for clusters  of region 2
2 for clusters  of region 3

As the whole point of me doing this clustering is so that I can segment the image into 3 regions.

Many thanks.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A:** Given that your matrix `output` contains scalar values ranging from 1 to 3, `imshow(output)` is treating this as a *grayscale* matrix and assuming that the full range of values is 0 to 255. This is why constraining the color limits is necessary as otherwise your image is all white or almost all white.

**B:** `output = output - 1`

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan. Very helpful and prompt answer. If I may extend the above question, how would I re-do the above in colour? I.e without converting the image from RGB to grayscale?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Ryan, your problem is probably just how you display the image. Here's a working example:

```
snow = rand(256, 256);
figure;
imagesc(snow);

nClusters = 3;
clusterIndices = kmeans(snow(:), nClusters);

figure;
imagesc(reshape(clusterIndices, [256, 256]));
```