# grayscale image processing using k-mean

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am trying to convert the rgb image into a grayscale and then cluster it using kmean function of matlab .

**here is my code**

```
he = imread('tumor2.jpg');

%convert into a grayscale image
ab=rgb2gray(he);
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);

%convert the image into a column vector
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,1);

%nColors=no of clusters
nColors = 3;
%cluster_idx is a n x 1 vector where cluster_idx(i) is the index of cluster assigned to ith pixel 
[cluster_idx, cluster_center ,cluster_sum] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',1,'EmptyAction','drop' );

figure;
%converting vector into a matrix of dimensions equal to that of original
%image dimensions (nrows x ncols)
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
pixel_labels
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
```

**problems**

1) output image is always a plain white image.
   i tried the solution given in the link below but output of the image is       a plain gray image in this case.

[find the solution tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690669/k-means-clustering-in-matlab-output-image)

2) when i execute my code second time ,execution does not proceed beyond k-mean function (it is likes an infinite loop there). hence no output in this case.

Comment: Can you post an example image?

Comment: It's curious, because if I set 30 `nColors` then I get 3 clusters for the cameraman image. Maybe someone with more experience in kmeans can help

Comment: Warning: Empty cluster created at iteration 1 during replicate 1

Comment: these warnings may be reason for only 3 clusters in the cameraman image.

Comment: I understand the warning. The algorithm tries to cluster and falls into local minima of the optimization where some of the clusters have no items. I explaied it in my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it looks like when you are colour segmenting `kmeans` is known to fall in local minima. This means that often, it wont find the amount of clusters you want as the minimization is not the best (that's why lots of people use other type of segmentation, such as level sets or simple region growing).

An option is to increase the amount of Replicates (amount of times kmeans will try to find the answer). At the moment you are setting it to 1, but you could try 3 or 4, and it may reach the solution that way.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379882/image-segmentation-using-k-means) question the accepted answer recommends to use a `kmeans` version of the algorithm specifically created for image segmentation. I havent tried myself but I think its worth a shot.

[Link to FEX](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8379-kmeans-image-segmentation/content/kmeans.m)